# How to I set a custom escape RegExp in a lodash template?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Here's what I'm trying:

```
_.template("Hello ___name___",{escape:/___(.*?)___/g})({name:"Steve"})
```

The output I would expect is:

> Hello Steve

But instead I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: _.template(...) is not a function(anonymous function)

Which makes sense because this:

```
_.template("Hello ___name___",{escape:/___(.*?)___/g})
```

Gives me back the string `Hello ___name___` instead of a template function.

Are [the docs](https://lodash.com/docs#template) wrong or what?

N.B. I don't want to override the global `_.templateSettings`.

Comment: 2.4.1 apparently. Didn't think to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use version `2.*` (in this version [`second argument`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/doc/README.md#_templatetext-data-options-optionsescape-optionsevaluate-optionsimports-optionsinterpolate-sourceurl-variable) is data for template), you can try this

```js
console.log(_.template("Hello ___name___", null, {escape:/___(.*?)___/g})({name:"Steve"}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

With version `3.*` your example works fine

```js
console.log(_.template("Hello ___name___", {escape:/___(.*?)___/g})({name:"Steve"}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.8.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh! That makes sense. I thought it was a documentation error, but I was just running an old version. Thank you!